# Is there any way to synchronize a acf field with custom post type( media attachment ) tag

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added `attachment_tag` taxonomy to WordPress attachments.

Now, I want it to be synchronized an acf field.

I tried using `edit_attachment` hook to update both fields, but the problem is how to know if one tag is added to the tag or removed from acf field and vice versa, in this situation `edit_attachment` is not helping me.

Besides this, if the acf field is somewhere else(a post using it as featured image and I would like to add/update attachment_tag in edit post page), it will never trigger `edit_attachment` hook, so I am unable to synchronize these two.

If anyone knows any better hook or another way, I can use to make it work, please let me know.

If anything else, I need to add to describe my situation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Part of answer:-**

Using `acf/update_value` like

```
add_filter('acf/update_value', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);

function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field  ) {
    // only do it to certain custom fields
    if( $field['name'] == 'custom_field' ) {

        // get the old (saved) value
        $old_value = get_field('custom_fields', $post_id);

        // get the new (posted) value
        $new_value = $_POST['acf']['custom_field'];
        if( $old_value != $new_value ) {
            //update here
        }
}
```

This is how it can be done out side attachment edit page.

**Now only problem is with attachment edit page.**